# Graph invariants for rooted trees

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, trees

I'm looking for a few graph invariants (that have been studied before) that help distinguish **rooted** trees. I have a large, real-world collection of these graphs and I'd like to see what has been looked at before I reinvent the wheel.

As an example, I've been considering the average distance from the root to all leaves.